# Can (and should) TLS be strict about the ciphers it supports?

Tags: tls, smtp

When trying to establish a TLS channel to outlook.com in order to relay SMTP traffic I get connection failures and have to continue without encryption.

An example of such a connection:

```
openssl s_client  -starttls smtp -crlf -connect x-com.mail.eo.outlook.com:25 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA  
CONNECTED(00000003)
139677700306600:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 343 bytes and written 137 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

According to the snipet above I attempt TLS using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA. Shouldn't there be a renegotiation until the two parties aggree and establish a TLS connection? What would happen if one of the parties is not capable to use all required ciphers and algorithms?

Comment: You _choose_ to continue without encryption because there's zero shared ciphers.  You could also choose not to continue in that case, if you value security over email availability.  You could also choose to support a broader array of ciphers and allow TLS negotiation to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Seeing your device runs recent openssl just fine, the choice of DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA as your favorite cipher seems quite eccentric. Slow (DHE) and not very secure (SHA-1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please don't confuse TLS negotiation with a bazaar were all parties negotiate and renegotiate until they find some common solution. Since every message needs time for delivery that would be much too slow. Thus there is only a single offer by the client which includes all ciphers the client is willing to support, in the order preferred by the client. If the server has support for any of these ciphers it will pick the best based on servers or clients preference. If there is no overlap the negotiation fails permanently.

In your case the server accepts the following ciphers (as determined by [this tool](https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl)):

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
AES256-SHA256
AES128-SHA256
AES256-SHA
AES128-SHA
DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Since you only offer a single cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA and this cipher is not supported by the server the negotiation fails.

Comment: In this case, it's probably kind-of more like a restaurant than a bazaar. You walk in saying "here's a list of the things (rather, the *one thing*) I'm *not* allergic to". The waiter looks at the list and says "sorry, we don't have any of that here".

Comment: Can you please include the command you used to get this cipher suite output? Many thanks!

Comment: @Georgios: I've added the link to the tool I've used to find out the ciphers. Other tools are [sslyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze/releases) which can probably do the same.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, TLS should be strict about the cipher suites it supports. Without careful cipher suite selection, you risk negotiating to an insecure cipher suite that may be compromised. If another party doesn't support a cipher suite that's up to your standards, and you highly value security on that connection, you shouldn't allow your system to operate with lower-quality cipher suites.

However, sensible TLS implementations also support multiple cipher suites to increase the chances of compatibility with other parties. Despite the many recent revelations of weaknesses in various cipher suites, there still remain several which are considered secure. So long as you only control one side of the conversation, it would be ridiculous to restrict your system to only supporting one cipher suite and then expect the whole Internet to operate according to your individual standards.

What's happening here is ***you're*** choosing to support *only* one cipher suite, and the other system is choosing *not* to support that one. (Only the owner of the other system can say why, but my guess would be it might have something to do with [Logjam](https://weakdh.org/).) However, the other system probably does support several other cipher suites which are equally (if not more) secure as the one you've selected. (Looks like @SteffenUllrich has the list.) Pick one of those that you're comfortable with, and configure your system to allow it.

Or just don't use TLS for that connection.

Or just don't talk to that server at all.

Your choice.